# How to specify possible values of map keys using annotations

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

As [Swagger Specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/) says there is a way explicitly to define fixed keys as object properties (see "Fixed Keys" section).

How to achieve the same thing using Swagger annotations? 
E.g.

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true)
private Map<SomeEnumA, SomeEnumB> field = new EnumMap<>(SomeEnumB.class);
```

So, I would like to see `SomeEnumA` entries as fixed keys of `field` property in the generated api spec.

Answer (score 0):

An example for response body using springdoc-openapi:

```java
@Operation(responses = @ApiResponse(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "object",
        requiredProperties = {"foo", "bar"}),
    schemaProperties = {
        @SchemaProperty(name = "foo", schema = @Schema(type = "number")),
        @SchemaProperty(name = "bar", schema = @Schema(type = "number")),
    })))
```

Results in:

[image]